# Can't install ubuntu by USB or from Windows

Tags: installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from official website and then made it to USB by Universal USB installer. Then I restarted laptop and chose "start from USB", but nothing happened except a black screen with a short dash line in the left top corner..
I also tried to install from Windows by wubi. After installation and reboot by choosing ubuntu, it showed "Normal booting"(something like that I can't remember). Then it stopped there and couldn't continue..

Now I use Win 7 Ultimate, memory is 4GB and processor is Intel Core 2 Duo T6400 @2GHz

Really appreciate for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Try using Unetbootin and selecting ubuntu 12.04 LTS from the list and making a bootable USB Flash drive that way...  Also, if your laptop has UEFI enabled then either disable it for Ubuntu or make sure you are installing the 64-bit edition so it works with your hardware...

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How to disable UEFI for Ubuntu and know my laptop works with 64-bit edition?

Answer (score 0):

in order to make a boot-able pen-drive, you better get the software from pendrivelinux.com 
and from the drop-down list of the softwre, choose version of Ubuntu(in your case 12.04) and the insert the location of the ISO file. after that click on create.
it will make your pen-drive boot-able.

after that, while starting the system, press F1/F2 (as supported by your BIOS)to enter the setup and set preference to boot from USB drive. Then when you will start your system, it will ask to boot from USB stick, select the option. It will take you to a menu, from where select try/install Ubuntu (as per your choice) and your ubuntu is now ready to use.

Comment: I did exactly same as you said. But it just stopped after booting from USB, with  black screen with a short dash line in the left top corner.. then didn't continue

Comment: Most possible reason could be that your pen-drive speed is slow and therefor it is taking more time, or some specifications are not met.                                              
       Also check the version of windows used in your system(from computer properties) and choose same version of ubuntu to install in pendrive.